# Azure Data Factory Parquet dynamic schema merge

Tags: azure, parquet, azure-data-factory

I have multiple Parquet files in a ADLS Gen2, the parquet files have different columns/schema, but all the different schemas are compatible with each other.
When I create a Dataset in ADF it only detects 26 out of the 68 columns (26 columns are found in every parquet file).
If I use Pyspark to read the files I can use following lines to merge the different schemas dynamically.

`parquetFile = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("./data/*/*/*/*/*/")`

Is there a way to have a similar setting in azure data factory?

Thank you and Kind Regards

Comment: Data Factory will using the file schema with 68 columns.

Comment: But it doesn't the data factory detects creates a schema with 26 columns.
Just to elaborate I have multiple files, one file can contain 20 columns the other one 35 and the third one 40 columns. The columns can be quite different. All in all over all the datasets I have unique 68 columns.